# What is the most efficient way to find out in how may ways 4 integers of an array sum upto an integer n?

Tags: arrays

I have an array of m integers and I want to check if there are 4 integers (repetition allowed) in the array which sum upto a given integer n.

For example, if there is an array [8, 4, 2,1], and n = 8, then possible combinations are - {2, 2, 2, 2}, {4,2, 1, 1}.

Currently, I am using 4 for loops to count as follows:

```
int ans = 0;

for(int a = 0; a<arr.size(); a++) {
    for(int b = 0; b<arr.size(); b++) {
        for(int c = 0; c<arr.size(); c++) {
            for(int d = 0; d<arr.size(); d++) {
                if(arr[a] + arr[b] + arr[c] + arr[d] == n) ans++;
            }
        }
    }
}

printf("%d", ans);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Sort the input array `X` removing duplicates.
2. Lazily produce variants, starting from the largest `C[0]^4`, down to the smallest `C[3]^4`, dropping sets of combinations where the partial products P{C[i]} exceeds the target `X`.
3. Stop as soon as the first element raised to 4th power `C[0]^4` is less than `X`
4. ...
5. Profit.

Usually, programming languages would provide partial or full support of the above algorithm. For instance in python you can lazily list all permutations of an array with `itertools` building blocks, so only the pruning logic is to be coded:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement as cwr

N = 4 # number of elements in the combination
X = [2, 3, 1, 5, 4, 3] # input array

for P in cwr(sorted(set(X), reverse=True), 4):
    print(P) // put checking logic instead of print
```

Comment: Looks like a modified brute force. What would be the time complexity? Is it about factorial (size of array)?

Comment: @user3243499 - I'd categorize it as [branch & bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound), so worst case - yes, factorial